# Does treatment with pyrimethamine and sulfadiazine eliminate reservoirs of Toxoplasma gondii?

Tags: treatment, antibiotics, toxoplasmosis

Toxoplasma gondii is known to be one of many pathogens that sequesters away in nerve cells, as well as cysts in the muscles and liver, to avoid the immune system. Standard treatment for severe infection — which is fairly rare as infection is usually asymptomatic or nearly so — is pyrimethamine and sulfadiazine.

Does combined treatment with these drugs also eliminate neuronal and other cyst reservoirs of T. gondii, or just those protists involved in an active infection?